# call a method of inner class from another class Java

Tags: java

I would like to call the `Salarycal()` method from Employee inner class `employeeInfo` to class `Exc`

```
public class Employee {

    public class employeeInfo{
            int id;
            String name;
            int Salary;


            public  employeeInfo(int id,String name,int Salary){
                this.id=id;
                this.name=name;
                this.Salary=Salary;

                System.out.println(id+name+Salary);
            }   
            public int Salarycal(){
                int totalSalary =0;
                int b=getId();
                           ........
            }
}
import Employer.Employee.employeeInfo;

public class Exc {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //want to access the salarycal() method in this class
        }

}
```

Comment: Well you need to have an instance of `employeeInfo`... have you got one? Why do you need this to be an inner class anyway? (I'd suggest using top-level classes for the most part...)

Comment: Also, just a style recommendation: please don't user lower-case names for classes.  Good habits now, less frustration with coworkers later ;)

Comment: lowercase class and uppercase method? This is really hard to read.

Comment: You also have to impliment The Setters and Getters for your paramaters , before using them ex:    int b=getId();   is not implimented to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I would usually invoke a method of inner class

```
Inner inner = new Outer().new Inner();
inner.methodToInvoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ashish said:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Employee().new employeeInfo().Salarycal();
}
```

PS. Read about [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)